# How to get data from ListBox Access in query

Tags: sql, ms-access

like my title says, I wanna get the data from the ListBox. I have a form with another form for picking art. numbers then in my other form, there is a query which is taking the art. number and give more information like the location. These Information are needed for the report which is a label. Now the problem is, there is a 1:n relation, because there are sometimes several locations for one art. number. So I tried making an ListField which has the Location from the query to make a pick between them. At first I tried to filter the location in my report but it doesnt worked for me. Yet I am trying to make an query for filtering the location. But everytime there is nothing in the table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [L-Ort1]
FROM NeueAbfrageForm
WHERE [L-Ort1] In (Forms![_Teilenummerneingabe3Form]![TestListe])
```

this is my query. L-Ort1 is the location and NeueAbfrageForm is the query used for ListBox and the second form in my form. TestListe is my ListBox

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few option the simplest is

```
Forms![_Teilenummerneingabe3Form]![TestListe].ItemData(x)
```

where x is the row number starting 0

If you select row in the listbox then do

```
Forms![_Teilenummerneingabe3Form]![TestListe].ItemsSelected(0)
```

and if you need different column then

```
 Forms![_Teilenummerneingabe3Form]![TestListe].Column(y,Forms![_Teilenummerneingabe3Form]![TestListe].ItemsSelected(0) )
```

where y is the column number starting 0